# Raster classes area calculation

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, area, reclassify

I have 3 raster layers each of them is classified into 4 classes and each one has defined weight value. I  had to to create FINAL raster by multiplying those 3 rasters with their weight values and adding those 3 togheter, I did that, as shown in the figure below.

[image]

Now, here is the problem, I want to calculate the area for each class in the FINAL raster that I created. That raster has also 4 classes. I used **raster layer uniqe values report** tool for that but I get this report bellow:

[image]

As you can see I have range of values, for example class 0 goes from 0,5 to 0,9 and each value has its own area, but I want to see only one class 0 with one area (so sum of these areas shown), one class 1 with its area etc. I dont need those ranges with their areas

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reclassify your raster. Use e.g. [Reclassify by Table](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#reclassify-by-table):

> This algorithm reclassifies a raster band by assigning new class
> values based on the ranges specified in a fixed table.

So you get an output raster, reduced to the number of classes you defined.

*This is how your reclassify dialog / Reclssification table could look like:*
[image]